# Stop changing '.' to ',' when culture changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

I have a webpage where for example a `1.0` turn into `2,0` when I change my `Culture`. Can you prevent this from happening when changing `Culture`?

Comment: Are you looking `InvariantCulture`? `string result = value.ToString(Culture.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Why would you want to override the culture settings though? There's a reason it wants to use `2,0`

Comment: Why would you want to? Part of changing culture is changing the numeric formats.

Comment: Wait, `1.0` turns into `2,0` ? How, where, for what culture?

Comment: @nvoigt I was guessing that was a typo

Comment: I have a data that compare the input from the webpage, when the culture is EN everything is fine but when I change to FR culture The data won't match. And I tried parsing my double with Culture info but the '.' won't turn into ',' no matter what I tried.

Comment: Then your comparison function is wrong.

Comment: lots of countries use comma instead of decimal and a decimal at place if comma. This is not typo. In that case 1,234.56 become 1.234,56

Comment: I'm getting the data from the Entity model and for some reason the separator stays as '.' when i'm comparing it.

Comment: If you are using numeric values instead of strings, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Fenrir you should show us the code which compares the strings. You should use `String.Compare(firstString, secondString, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);` in there is our guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the (number)DecimalSeperator you want yourself in the culture you use:

```
double number = 2.4;

CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
// Make a writable clone
culture = (CultureInfo)culture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator= ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Console.WriteLine(number); //prints 2.4

culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Console.WriteLine(number); //prints 2,4
```

There is also the number group seperator:

```
number = 123232;
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator= ",";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Console.WriteLine(number); //prints 123,232
```